# estimate the error term in CLT

Tags: pr.probability, st.statistics, inequalities, asymptotics

Let $X_m = \frac{1}{\sqrt{m}}\sum_{k=1}^m Z_k$ where $Z_k$ are iid equally likely on $\{\pm 1\}$. Then $X_m$ convergens to $X \sim \mathcal{N}(0,1)$ in distribution by CLT.

Let $f$ be a smooth bounded function on $\mathbb{R}$. Then $\mathbb{E}[f(X_m)] \to \mathbb{E}[f(X)]$. I wonder if there is any general method to give sharp asymptotic estimate of the error term $\mathbb{E}[f(X_m)] - \mathbb{E}[f(X)]$, which I expect to be $\Theta(1/m)$. The scaling constant should depend on $f$ (as well as the distribution of $Z_k$ if they are not binary).

For law of large number, this type of estimate can be done via the [Delta method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delta_method) (e.g., to estimate $\mathbb{E}[f(\bar{Z})] - f(0)$). There must be a counterpart for CLT... I haven't found the [Edgeworth expansion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edgeworth_series) useful because it seems to work with distribution with densities.

**Edited:** To be clear, I am only interested in some specific nice function (e.g., $f(x) = x^2 e^{-x^2/4}$) and finding a sharp expansion for the error term of the form, say, $c/m + o(1/m)$, where $c$ will depend n $f$. As pointed by Mark, the worst-case rate of all bounded smooth function $f$ is $1/\sqrt{m}$, which agrees with the upper bound given by Stein's method.

Comment: Do you perhaps mean to look at $f(\bar{X})$ instead of $f(X_m)$? For $f(x)=x^2$ your error term doesn't converge to 0.

Comment: No. I meant $f(X_m)$. For your $f$ the error term is zero.

Comment: oh...Z's are symmetric...so the error term is 0 regardless of m, right?

Comment: well if something converges to Gaussian weakly, then all its moments must converge.

Comment: Counterpart of Central Limit Theorem gives the distribution of $\sqrt{n}f(\bar{X})$. Distribution of $f(\sqrt{n}\bar{X})$ seems to have unusual behavior, for instance if $Z_i$'s are uniform on {0,1}, mean of $X_m$ goes to infinity, but because $f$ is bounded, distribution of $f(X_m)$ gets squished into a delta function

Comment: why is the behavior unusual? $f(\sqrt{m} \bar{X})$ converges in distribution to the image measure of standard normal under $f$. This only requires continuity of $f$.

Comment: Is $f$ bounded over all of $\mathbb{R}$, because the two polynomial examples discussed so far aren't, right?  Are the $Z_k$ uniform on $\lbrace -1, 1 \rbrace$ or do you want to consider more general cases, as the parenthetical at the end of para two suggests? 

Comment: OK, maybe "uninteresting" behavior rather than unusual. If mean is not 0, limiting distribution is a delta distribution. Also, CLT-type theorems for (properly scaled) distribution of $f(\bar{n})$ don't require f to be bounded.

Comment: sure. let's focus on the case where the sum is properly centralized and normalized.

Comment: I take it back, if Stein considers this, it must be interesting :) BTW, equation 37 in his book also requires f' to be bounded.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your conjecture is correct. 
Suppose that (say) $f$ has a bounded $5$th derivative. Then
\begin{equation}
 Ef(X_m) - Ef(X)=-\frac{Ef''''(X)+o(1)}{12m}. \tag{1}
\end{equation}
Indeed, let 
\begin{equation}
 Z_{mj}:=\frac{Z_j}{\sqrt m},\quad Y_{mj}:=\frac{Y_j}{\sqrt m},\quad T_{mk}:=\sum_{j=1}^{k-1}Z_{mj}+\sum_{j=k+1}^m Y_{mj}, 
\end{equation}
where $Z_1,\dots,Z_m,Y_1,\dots,Y_m$ are independent random variables and $Y_j\sim N(0,1)$. 
Note that $EZ_{mj}^p=EY_{mj}^p$ for $p=0,\dots,3$, $EZ_{mj}^4=\tfrac1{m^2}$, $EY_{mj}^4=\tfrac3{m^2}$. 
Also, $Z_{mk}$ is independent of $T_{mk}$ for each $k$, and so is $Y_{mk}$. 
Moreover, $Ef''''(T_{mk})\to Ef''''(X)$ uniformly in $k=1,\dots,m$ (as $m\to\infty$); this should be as easy to show as the convergence $Ef(X_m) \to Ef(X)$, mentioned in the question.

Now one has
\begin{equation}
 Ef(X_m) - Ef(X)=\sum_{k=1}^m D_k, \tag{2}
\end{equation}
where
\begin{equation}
 D_k:=E[f(T_{mk}+Z_{mk})-f(T_{mk}+Y_{mk})]
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
 =\sum_{p=0}^4\frac1{p!}\,Ef^{(p)}(T_{mk})E(Z_{mk}^p-Y_{mk}^p)+O(E(|Z_{mk}|^5+|Y_{mk}|^5))
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
 =\tfrac1{4!}\,(Ef''''(X)+o(1))(\tfrac1{m^2}-\tfrac3{m^2})+O(m^{-5/2}) 
\end{equation}
by Taylor's expansion, 
with $o(1)$ uniform in $k=1,\dots,m$. 
Now $(1)$ follows immediately from $(2)$.

Answer (score 3):

Stein's method typically gives good Berry-Esseen type bounds for smooth test functions.  See Chapter III of [Stein's book](http://books.google.com/books?id=6C2g7_-KnhsC&lpg=PP1&dq=approximate%2520computation%2520of%2520expectations&pg=PP1#v=onepage&q&f=false) (entirely viewable in Google Books).  For example, specializing to your case of symmetric Bernoulli summands, equation (37) on p. 38 gives
$$
\vert \mathbb{E}f(X_m)-\mathbb{E}f(X)\vert \le \frac{2\Vert f' \Vert_\infty}{\sqrt{m}}.
$$
For more general summands, there is some simple dependence on the third and fourth moments as well as $\Vert f \Vert_\infty$.

Also, I'm pretty sure that $m^{-1/2}$ is the correct rate here even for Bernoullis, although I can't find a reference for a lower bound at the moment.  Why do you expect better?

Comment: Mark, thanks for your reply. See my example below. Maybe I made a mistake?

Comment: It might be the case, that the answer to the question [Estimates for the normal approximation of the binomial distribution](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1290246/estimates-for-the-normal-approximation-of-the-binomial-distribution) will help for the lower bound...

Answer (score 1):

The [Berry-Esseen theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Berry%E2%80%93Esseen_theorem) is a classical result of this sort.  It predicts errors on the order of $m^{-1/2}$, however.

Comment: I didn't find Berry-Esseen directly applicable. It deals with CDF , that is, those $f$ which is indicator of a half-open interval. Maybe you can enlighten me how to do it. In fact I am more interested in lower bound. To give an example why $m^{-1/2}$ is not tight, consider $f(x) = x^4$. Then the error term equals $2/m$.

Comment: @mr.gondolier:  Is $f(x) = x^4$ allowed? You state in the question that $f(x)$ is bounded.

Comment: My argument is as follows: if an unbounded function like $x \mapsto x^4$ has an error term like $1/m$, I am positive that we can find a bounded function (e.g. by truncation) whose error term does not exceed $1/m$, which is strictly smaller than $1/\sqrt{m}$ Nate stated.

Comment: BTW, results giving error on the order of $m^{-1/2}$ assume non-zero derivatives. In your case, $f(\bar{X})$ converges to 0 at the rate of $m^{-2}$, this follows from Taylor expansion of $f(\bar{X})$ around 0

Answer (score 1):

If $X_m$ has cumulative distribution function $F_m$, 
and $X$ has cumulative distribution function $F$, then
(at least formally) integration by parts gives you
$$E(f(X_m))-E(f(X))=\int (F_m(x)-F(x)) df(x).$$
Now you can apply the Berry-Esseen bound.

Comment: Also instead of Berry-Esseen it is better to apply non-uniform Berry-Esseen, i.e. something like (do not remember the constants exactly) $$ |F_m(x) - F(x)| \le {\mathrm{const}\over\sqrt{m}} {1\over 1+x^3} $$

Answer (score 0):

Sorry this is NOT an answer to my question... just some clarafications.

The reason I think $m^{-1/2}$ is not tight is as follows. For example, take $f$ to be the characteristic function, we have

$\mathbb{E}[e^{itX_m}] = (\mathbb{E}[e^{it Z/\sqrt{m}}])^m = (1 - t^2/(2m) + o(1/m))^m \to e^{-t^2/2} = \mathbb{E}[e^{itX}]$

at rate $1/m$, because $m\log(1-1/m) \to -1$ at rate $1/m$.

Also, it seems all moments of $X_m$ converge to the moments of $X$ at rate $1/m$. Doing a Taylor expansion for those nice $f$ should also yield a rate of $1/m$?

Comment: I'm not convinced by your heuristic for the characteristic function because you only get the $1/m$ rate for convergence of the log once $m \gg t^2$.  So your argument shows that $\mathbb{E} e^{itX_m} \to \mathbb{E} e^{itX}$ at rate $1/m$, but with an implicit constant that may depend on $t$.  Likewise, if $f$ is a polynomial, then $\mathbb{E} f(X_m) \to \mathbb{E} f(X)$ at rate $1/m$ with an implicit constant that may depend on the degree and coefficients of $f$.  If, as you suggest above, you do a truncation and Taylor expansion you may lose some of that rate.

Comment: Just to clarify: You are correct about the $1/m$ rate for certain very nice functions, but I think that for the class of all bounded smooth functions the correct rate is $1/\sqrt{m}$, and that the loss is somehow due to the lack of uniformity in that $1/m$ rate for very nice functions.

Comment: I agree that there exists $f$ such that $1/sqrt{m}$ is tight. In fact I am not looking for uniform estimates but rather for a specific function $f(x) = x^2 e^(-x^2/4)$. In my OP, I said the scaling constant will depend on the function $f$. Based also on numerical result, I believe its rate is $1/m$. Do you think there is any method to produce a sharp expansion of the form $c/m + o(1/m)$? Any lower bound idea?

Comment: Okay, so you only expect $1/m$ for a *specific* $f$ you're interested in. You should edit the original question to make that clear, since it sounds like you're saying you expect $1/m$ for an arbitrary smooth bounded $f$.  (I don't have an answer offhand but I'll think about it when I have some time.)